# How to loop a song in youtube?

Tags: chrome-for-android, youtube

I used to listen to some favourite song in youtube (Android). I would like to loop so it plays all time till I stop. Previously I have tried using Chrome web browser. It work to loop, but no sound. So, I forget it.

the my question is, is any way how to do it? In the case of Chrome, is any specific version I have to use to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome latest on Play Store `72.0.3626. 105`

Open Chrome in Desktop mode (Settings→Desktop site) , paste YouTube  link and click on the video to reveal menu as shown. Select "Loop"

[image]

Comment: I check my chrome version, it is exactly the same with yours. I did exactly as you mentioned, but no sound. It loop, but no sound.

Comment: I can't say why. It works fine for me and this is something that has been working for nearly two years for me. Check your earphone, volume, uninstall and install Chrome

Comment: Thats quite confusing. The missing sound is only of the youtube being playing in the chrome browser. The other sounds are mormal.

Comment: IDK. I tried with three videos. Try a different video. This is the link in answer https://youtu.be/c3O0PhhD6B4

Comment: Now you know the reason. KitKat doesn't support this Chrome version

Comment: What is that mean "**kitkat doesn't support this chrome version?**"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89879/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-aircraft-lover).