# No sound playing in Chrome web browser

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, audio, chrome-for-android, youtube

I would like to [loop a song of YouTube](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207952/how-to-loop-a-song-in-youtube), so I need to play it in Chrome browser rather than in the YouTube mobile application. The loop itself is working fine, but unfortunately there is no sound playing. I am using Chrome 72.0.3626.105 which is running in Android 4.4.4 KitKat.

What is probably the problem? Sound other than in Chrome is working fine. So, it is clear that the problem is with the browser, not other part.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome which you are using is targeting `minsdk 24` which corresponds to Nougat and you are on KitKat so you shouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work properly (you can check the manifest using many apps available to determine sdk level- just search for manifest on Play Store )

You can search Chrome version that is compatible and download from third party sources of your choice. Related [Install Google Chrome for old tablet / phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167188/131553)

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer it works fine for me on Pie